# ActionSheet not opaque the background view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiactionsheet

I have a problem when i call my actionSheet, the problem is that when i call my actionsheet the view thats is behind of the actionsheet is opaque and i want to see the backgroung not opaque.

I have tried [actionSheet setOpaque:NO] but not make anything, how i can solve it?

http://pastie.org/3123759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of action sheet take a custom picker and try to do the code that u need.It may solve your problem.But by default the action sheet take semi black background.